# Libgdx disable texturing and add colorize

Tags: android, libgdx

Is there any way to disable texturing and enable colorizing a model at runtime?
And later enable again the texturing?

Now I am using this:

```
@Override
public void enableTexture(boolean enable, Vector3 colorize) {
    enableTexture(enable, colorize.x, colorize.y, colorize.z);
}

@Override
public void enableTexture(boolean enable, float r, float g, float b) {
    if (enable) objModel.getModelInstance().materials.get(0).set(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(objModel.getTexture()));
    else {
        objModel.getModelInstance().materials.get(0).set(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(r, g, b, 1));
    }
}
```

but this is not very good for performance, because it is allways create a new object at runtime. I need this for light shaft

**final working code:**

```
@Override
public void enableTexture(boolean enable, float r, float g, float b) {
    if (enable) {
        if (diffuse == null) diffuse = TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(objModel.getTexture());
        objModel.getModelInstance().materials.get(0).clear();
        objModel.getModelInstance().materials.get(0).set(diffuse);
    }
    else {
        if (color == null) color = ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(r, g, b, 1);
        objModel.getModelInstance().materials.get(0).clear();
        objModel.getModelInstance().materials.get(0).set(color);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Attributes class to get the specific Attribute.
When loading before the game is running create the Attributes.

```
private Attributes attributes

public void create() {

    this.attributes = new Attributes();

    this.attributes.set(
            TextureAttribute.createDiffuse( this.region ),
            ColorAttribute.createDiffuse( Color.WHITE )
    );
}
```

When the game is running you can now use the get method.

```
public Attribute getAttribute( boolean enable, float r, float g, float b ){

    if ( enable ) {
        TextureAttribute attribute = (TextureAttribute) attributes.get( TextureAttribute.Diffuse );
        attribute.set( this.region );

        return attribute;
    } else {
        ColorAttribute attribute = (ColorAttribute) attributes.get( ColorAttribute.Diffuse );
        attribute.color.set( r, g, b, 1 );

        return attribute;
    }
}
```